# Authentication using Service Account in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, service-accounts

I am developing my own CLI in Python to manage certain operations in Google Cloud Platform services via GCP APIs/Python Client libraries.

More specifically, I will manage Resource Manager, Cloud Storage, BigQuery and Deployment Manager.

I created a central GCP Project and a Service Account with fully permissions in the organization node, and this account will act on behalf of any user to manage those services and perform operations like for example, create/delete deployments via Deployment Manager API call.

My question is how should I handle Authentication in each API/Client call. Since the CLI will make the call to the different services on behalf of human users, I would like to use Service Account.
I know we can generate keys for a Service Account and read its content using a function like `service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(key.json)` but then if another colleague wants to run my CLI I have to send them the generated key json file and point to it locally and obviously I don't want to expose the key into a github repository.

I already tried using the following functions and it works fine but I need to pass the key.json file as argument forcing any other user to place locally the file and point to the path:

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient import discovery
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        'service_account_key.json')
service = discovery.build('cloudresourcemanager', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
request = service.projects().list()
response = request.execute()
```

Is it possible to authenticate a Service Account programmatically in a way I don't have to send the key json file to someone that will run the CLI?

Comment: Think thru your question. If this was possible, anyone could access any account. You have two choices, use a service account JSON file or implement OAuth and use User Account credentials. However, I wrote an article yesterday that almost gets around this. This might be a workable situation for you: https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-go-identity-based-access-control/ The magic is that you can give your users a service account JSON file that has zero permissions. This downloads in memory a service account which has permissions. This is not a secure solution, but better than full JSON keys.

Comment: Is it possible to "link" just the personal accounts that has access to the GCP Project (where the Service Account was created) with the Service Account keys?   That way although everyone runs the CLI, just will work for those who has permissions in the GCP project.

Comment: Please explain your comment in more detail as I am not sure what you are asking. There is no relationship (inside GCP) between a service account and a user account. Not even for the identity that created the service account. Also, a service account is not tied to one project. A service can be used with any project provided that IAM permissions are granted.